# Switch case for event listeners sometimes retriggers event

Tags: javascript

I'm using a switch statement to handle keydown events for a music player app. Sometimes when you press spacebar, it results in the event retriggering (you can see what I mean in the [live version](https://nataliecardot.com/music-player/)) - the song pauses, the intended result, but instead of staying paused, it pauses for an instant then plays again. Why does this happen?

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
  switch (e.code) {
    case 'ArrowLeft':
      prevSong();
      break;
    case 'ArrowRight':
      nextSong();
      break;
    case 'Space':
      const isPlaying = musicContainer.classList.contains('play');
      isPlaying ? pauseSong() : playSong();
      break;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue isn't the switch, once the play button is clicked, it get focused, when pressing spacebar the browser understand it was an event from the button. Use `playBtn.blur()` to remove focus, like so:

```
playBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const isPlaying = musicContainer.classList.contains('play');

  playBtn.blur();

  isPlaying ? pauseSong() : playSong();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I personally only use `switch` when I absolutely need to. This is how I would do it:

```js
document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
    if (e.code == 'ArrowLeft') {
        prevSong();
    }
    else if (e.code == 'ArrowRight') {
        nextSong();
    }
    else if (e.code == 'Space') {
        (musicContainer.className.includes('play')) ? pauseSong() : playSong();
    }
};
```

I understand that not everyone does stuff the way I prefer, so your issue may be fixed by changing `classList.contains` to `className.includes`. Like so:

```js
document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
    switch (e.code) {
        case 'ArrowLeft':
            prevSong();
            break;
        case 'ArrowRight':
            nextSong();
            break;
        case 'Space':
            const isPlaying = (musicContainer.className.includes('play'));
            isPlaying ? pauseSong() : playSong();
            break;
    }
});
```